# Can Button[] generate output without using Print[]?

Tags: front-end, interface, button

`Button[]` beguiles me.  A simple example follows:

```
b1 = Button["Evaluate", Cos[Pi/6], Method -> "Queued"]
b2 = Button["Evaluate", Print[Cos[Pi/6]], Method -> "Queued"]
```

Both of the above statements produce buttons.  When one clicks on `b1`, it appears to evaluate something, but does not output or display anything.  Clicking on `b2` displays the expected output.

But clicking a second time on `b2` prints the expected result a second time.  Continuing to click on `b2` just increases the list of printed results.  This uselessly clutters the notebook I want to distribute.

I want a `Button[]` to execute a function and simply display its results as near as possible to what pressing **`Shift + Return`** in an input cell would do.

I further want it to overwrite previous output.

Ideally I would place the `Button[]` expression in a hidden initialization cell so only the actual button appears in the deployed notebook.

Does anyway exist to get a Button to do what I've described?  How?

Comment: Good question.  In normal evaluation `CellPrint` overwrites the previous output but it does not work from within `Button`, at least as I tried it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard -- Any thoughts on why the difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
y = 0; 
b1 = Button["Evaluate", y = Cos[Pi/6] (++y), Method -> "Queued"]
Dynamic@y
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I must not have made described what I need to do clearly.  When I click the Button a 2nd or 3rd time I need it to completely overwrite the output, neither adding to a list of printed results nor nesting the evaluation as you show above.  In use I'll have some input variables that may get changed between the times someone clicks the button.  I want a Button that will simply evaluate an expression and give me the same output I'd get from evaluating an input cell.  Still, I wonder if you've pointed me in a productive direction.  I'll try some things.  Thx.

Comment: @Jagra _My_ evaluation is recursive just because I wanted it.You may evaluate whatever you want

Comment: Got it working.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes Dynamic is not really needed. In Version 9 you can use the nice new Cells[]
construct. So the button could look like

```
CellPrint@ExpressionCell[Button["Evaluate",
   NotebookDelete[Cells[CellTags -> "calculationbutton"]];
   CellPrint@ExpressionCell[Cos[Pi/6],
     "Output", CellTags -> "calculationbutton"], Method -> "Queued"], 
  "Text"]
```

And I would also just close the instruction cell to hide it, e.g.:

```
Cell[CellGroupData[{Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"CellPrint", "@", 
  RowBox[{"ExpressionCell", "[", 
   RowBox[{
    RowBox[{"Button", "[", 
     RowBox[{"\"\<Evaluate\>\"", ",", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
      RowBox[{
       RowBox[{"NotebookDelete", "[", 
        RowBox[{"Cells", "[", 
         RowBox[{"CellTags", "->", "\"\<calculationbutton\>\""}], 
         "]"}], "]"}], ";", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
       RowBox[{"CellPrint", "@", 
        RowBox[{"ExpressionCell", "[", 
         RowBox[{
          RowBox[{"Cos", "[", 
           RowBox[{"Pi", "/", "6"}], "]"}], ",", 
          "\[IndentingNewLine]", "\"\<Output\>\"", ",", 
          RowBox[{
          "CellTags", "\[Rule]", "\"\<calculationbutton\>\""}]}], 
         "]"}]}]}], ",", 
      RowBox[{"Method", "\[Rule]", "\"\<Queued\>\""}]}], "]"}], ",", 
    "\"\<Text\>\""}], "]"}]}]], "Input",
 CellGroupingRules->{GroupTogetherGrouping, 10000.}],

Cell[BoxData[
 ButtonBox["\<\"Evaluate\"\>",
  Appearance->Automatic,
  ButtonFunction:>(NotebookDelete[
     Cells[CellTags -> "calculationbutton"]]; CellPrint[
     ExpressionCell[
      Cos[Pi/6], "Output", CellTags -> "calculationbutton"]]),
  Evaluator->Automatic,
  Method->"Queued"]], "Text",
 CellGroupingRules->{GroupTogetherGrouping, 10000.},
 GeneratedCell->True,
 CellAutoOverwrite->True]
}, {2}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to make the button disable itself.

```
DynamicModule[{enabled = True}, 
  Dynamic@Button["Evaluate", enabled = False; Print[Cos[Pi/6]], 
  Method -> "Queued", Enabled -> enabled]]
```

Before clicking on the button

[image: before-clicking]

After clicking

[image: after-clicking]

Answer (score 2):

I realise this question is old, but in my quest to find a solution to a similar problem to OP I have come up with a solution using CellTags and FrontEndExecute (like Rolf M). I try to avoid Dynamic.

Create a cell tag for the cell you want to evaluate with a button. This approach will Evaluate all cells with the same CellTag and depending on the scenario this could be advantageous.

In my example I used the CellTag "cellToEvaluate". (Select CellTag from front-end Cell menu to add cell tags.)

Create a Button that finds and evaluates cells with that CellTag.

```
Button["Evaluate",FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[NotebookLocate["cellToEvaluate"],"Evaluate"]]]
```

[image: example]