# How can I get a Button to evaluate an expression containing Get?

Tags: button, output

I have problems making `Button` evaluate an input like this one:

```
Button["Load", Get["/Users/simonlausen/Desktop/Input/ex1.mx"]]
```

I have tried a bunch of things, but haven't found any elegant solution. What to do?

Comment: Button has a time-out of 5 seconds. Add the options Method-> "Queued" to remove the time-out. (default is "Preemptive"). It's documented.

Comment: `Method -> "Queued"` is almost always the answer to questions about buttons that don't work as expected when the button action requiers _Mathematica_ to do something that takes some time. I have posted a list of some of the previous similar question [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/436/candidate-topics-posts-for-canonical-questions/933#933). This question might be considered a duplicate on any of these.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is that the main link has to evaluate the `Get` call. Reusing Mr.Wizards test:

```
Export["testfile.m", "Print[2+2]; f[x_]:=Sin[x]", "String"]
Button["Load", Get["testfile.m"], Method -> "Queued"]
```

works for me. For an explanation what I mean with *main link* you could check the chat log. I don't know whether it is good practice to include links of this here.

http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8608385#8608385

Comment: `Method -> "Queued"` does not help with the example I gave.  It may help when loading a package takes longer than the time-out, but I'm not sure if that is the problem the OP is having or if it is more akin to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18457/121).

Comment: That chat discussion should be part of a canonical answer! Don't we have a question that requires explicitly this?

Answer (score 0):

One can see that the `Get` operation does work, but simple output is suppressed:

```
Export["testfile.m", "Print[2+2]; Sin[1]", "String"]

Button["Load", << "testfile.m"]
```

When the button is clicked `4` is printed, but `Sin[1]` is not.

This is the same as: `Button["Go", Sin[1]]` which also does not print when the button is clicked.

If `Get` is used directly:

```
<< "testfile.m"
```

> 4
>
> ```
> Sin[1]
> ```

At the moment I cannot recall how to get the plain output printed to the evaluation Notebook.

EDIT: It appears there is no simple way:

[Can Button[] generate output without using Print[]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18457/121)