# Is it possible to create Evaluatable cell which will be automatically overwritten?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, automation

Am trying to generate an `Evaluatable` cell which itself is an output cell which will be overwritten when the original `Input` cell will be evaluated again:

```
CellPrint[
 ExpressionCell[Defer[1 + 1], "Output", Evaluatable -> True, 
  CellAutoOverwrite -> True, GeneratedCell -> True]]
```

Without `Evaluatable -> True` everything works as expected: the generated output cell is automatically overwritten when the input cell is evaluated again. But adding `Evaluatable -> True` breaks this behavior.

Is it possible to generate `Evaluatable` cell which will be automatically overwritten?

Comment: I would like to know the context of this question.  Even without `Evaluatable -> True` I can still evaluate the `1 + 1` cell so I am wondering where `Evaluatable -> True` is necessary.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `Evaluatable -> True` is necessary for work of the `InitializationCell -> True` option. Without `Evaluatable -> True` initialization cells are simply ignored.

Answer (score 5):

This will do what you want, without having to resort to SelectionMove or something silly like that. Of course, it does not use CellAutoOverwrite, so possibly this is not the "yes" you would have hoped for. The same can probably be achieved using CellID, but I'm not sure how that works.

```
NotebookDelete[Cells[CellTags -> "@#$kill me"]]
CellPrint[
  ExpressionCell[Defer[1 + 1], "Output", GeneratedCell -> True, 
   Evaluatable -> True, CellTags -> "@#$kill me" ]];
```

Edit: I misread a comment by you on an [answer to your other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23136/4330). I suppose you don't want to automatically evaluate the printed Cell after all, correct?

Comment: +1. Yes, I just need to print the cell, not to evaluate it.

Comment: I'm sorry. It seems I accidentally downvoted your answer. It was not on purpose and you got now a +1 from me.

Comment: @halirutan Maybe I care too much about votes, but I really appreciate your clarification :).

Answer (score 4):

This behavior does appear to be directly tied to the `Evaluatable` option as I will show.

Unfortunately I don't have a solution.  I offer these observations:

With the code in the question:

```
ExpressionCell[Defer[1 + 1], "Output",
  CellAutoOverwrite -> True,
  GeneratedCell -> True
] // CellPrint
```

The generated cell is overwritten, and you can still evaluate the output cell by placing the cursor within it and using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.  It is converted to an Input cell, but an `"Output"` cell is converted to Input even if the option `Evaluatable -> True` is used.

With style `"Input"` the generated cell is not overwritten:

```
ExpressionCell[Defer[1 + 1], "Input",
  CellAutoOverwrite -> True,
  GeneratedCell -> True
] // CellPrint
```

But it *is* overwritten if we add `Evaluatable -> False`:

```
ExpressionCell[Defer[1 + 1], "Input",
  CellAutoOverwrite -> True,
  GeneratedCell -> True,
  Evaluatable -> False
] // CellPrint
```

Comment: Note that the option Evaluatable determines whether we can use NotebookEvaluate to evaluate it, as well as SelectionEvaluate, as well as FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["EvaluateInitialization"]]. However we can extract the data using another cell, as I show [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23168/4330)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The `"Input"` style contains `Evaluatable -> True` option. Even without style specification this option triggers the automatic overwriting.

Comment: @Jacob Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: @Alexey Yes, that's my observation.  I wish I had a solution but I do not.  It would also let me answer [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18457/121) in the way I had hoped to.