# NotebookWrite an expression

Tags: notebooks

I'm trying to write a notebook from the kernel, so using one list of elements in one document, I'd like to create a second document with some interactions between the elements of the list.

For that, I'm already trying to write on a separate document, which works with

```
 NotebookWrite[ newDoc, Cell[ "2+3", "Input"]]
```

Now, this works fine, but I'm trying to get this string "2+3" computed in the new notebook. Nor using ToExpression, Evaluate seems to be working.

Any help for this? Also: is there a good book explaining these different concepts of how the Kernel works? I'm reading the online documentation, but sometimes, I'd like to have a more "book"-approach, if possible. What would you recommend?

Thanks all, once again!

Comment: Maybe `NotebookWrite[newDoc, Cell["2+3", "Input"], All];
SelectionEvaluate[newDoc]` ?

Comment: "The Mathematica book" has a chapter called "Manipulating Notebooks from the Kernel" : http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/book/section-2.11.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's set things up first

```
newDoc = NotebookPut[Notebook[{}]]
NotebookWrite[newDoc, Cell["2+3", "Input"]]
```

If you don't mind evaluating the whole notebook, you could do

```
NotebookEvaluate[newDoc, InsertResults -> True]
```

If you only want to evaluate that cell, may want to consider setting a `CellTag` for your Cell. For example

```
NotebookWrite[newDoc, Cell["2+3", "Input", CellTags-> "targetCell"]]
```

then you can evaluate only this `Cell` by using

```
NotebookEvaluate[newDoc, InsertResults -> True, 
 EvaluationElements -> {"Tags" -> {"targetCell"}}]
```

Note that if you want to insert `Cell`'s in this way, it is probably a good idea to make nice box expressions instead of just strings like "2+3". An alternative would then be

```
NotebookWrite[newDoc, Cell[ RowBox[{"2", "+", "3"}]], "Input", CellTags-> "targetCell"]]
```

You can find the boxes by using Show Expression from the Cell menu.

The syntax of the option `EvaluationElements` is a bit confusing to me. See also [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23164/4330), which is very closely related.