# Why are CellPrint cells not overwritten?

Tags: documentation

Quoting https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellPrint.html

> Cells generated by `CellPrint` by default have `GeneratedCell->True`, so that they are overwritten if they are regenerated.

An example from https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html:

```
CellPrint[
  Function[{n}, 
    ExpressionCell[Defer[Integrate[x^n Exp[-x], {x, 0, 1}]], "Input"]]
  /@ Range[5]
]
```

If I put that example code in a new cell in a new notebook and excute it (shift+enter) multiple times, the ouputs are not overwritten.  I expected they would be.  What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: The `"Input"` option seems to override that default. Try http://wolfram.com/xid/0j40bj4y-da8z6e and compare it to the behavior of `CellPrint[ExpressionCell[N[Pi, 20]]]`.

Comment: Actually, if one uses Cell ► Show Expression, one can see that in both cases `GeneratedCell->True, CellAutoOverwrite->True`.

Comment: Strongly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23149/280