# Easy printing of executable code

Tags: output-formatting, hold, debugging

I'm working on a package that has functions that call other existing and packaged functions.  I'd like a way to output what some of those key calls are, so users can see what's happening under the hood and for debugging purposes.

Here's a minimal example that wraps around `NDSolve`:

```
ex[eqns_, unks_, tmax_] := (
  Print["NDSolve[", eqns, ", ", unks, ", {t, 0, ", tmax, "}]"]; (* output code *)
  NDSolve[eqns, unks, {t, 0, tmax}]
)

ex[{n'[t] == n[t] (1 - n[t]), n[0] == 0.01}, {n}, 10]
```

> NDSolve[{n'[t]==(1-n[t]) n[t],n[0]==0.01}, {n}, {t, 0, 10}]
>
> {{n->InterpolatingFunction[...]}}

This approach basically works but has two issues I'd like to fix:

Issue 1: The output code is ugly and a minor hassle to write correctly.

Issue 2: If you copy and paste the output cell, it comes out as

```
"NDSolve["{n'[t]==(1-n[t]) n[t],n[0]==0.01`}", "{n}", {t, 0, "10"}]"
```

which isn't executable.  I'd want to get:

```
NDSolve[{n'[t]==(1-n[t]) n[t],n[0]==0.01}, {n}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Any ideas on how to address either (or hopefully both) of these issues?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could define a function similar to `Echo` with the difference that it won't evaluate its argument before printing.

```
SetAttributes[echo, HoldAll]

echo[expr_] := (CellPrint@
   ExpressionCell[Defer[expr], CellDingbat -> ">"];
   expr)
```

Then just put it in front of anything you want printed:

```
ex[eqns_, unks_, tmax_] := echo@NDSolve[eqns, unks, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

Let's try it:

```
ex[{n'[t] == n[t] (1 - n[t]), n[0] == 0.01}, {n}, 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The output is copyable.

---

`Print` should work fine instead of `CellPrint`/`ExpressionCell`. I used `CellPrint` so I would be able to add a [`CellDingbat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellDingbat.html).

---

Caveat: If `eqns`, `unks`, etc. were not directly substituted (e.g. if they were `Module` or `Block` variables) then their name would be printed instead of their value. Use `With` to directly substitute any value you want to print.  For example,

```
In[20]:= fun[] := Module[{x = 2},
  echo[x^2]
  ]

In[21]:= fun[]

> x$21572^2

Out[21]= 4

In[22]:= fun[] := Module[{x = 2},
  With[{x = x}, echo[x^2]]
  ]

In[23]:= fun[]

> 2^2

Out[23]= 4
```

---

If you want to turn off debugging, simply set `ClearAll[echo]; echo[x_] := x`.

Comment: `ExpressionCell[ Defer[expr], "Input",  CellDingbat -> ">"]` will even be directly evaluatable.

Comment: @Kuba Can you make it so that: 1. the echo output will be replaced when re-evaluating the input (`GeneratedCell -> True` did not help) 2. the output won't inherit the style (dingbat, colour) of the echo output if the input is re-evaluated

Comment: `CellAutoOverwrite -> True` should do. About 2), didn't get it and have to go. Will check later.

Comment: This is great, thanks!

Comment: @Kuba `CellAutoOverwrite -> True` didn't seem to fix the issue Szabolcs raised, but not having direct evaluability isn't such a big deal.

Comment: [This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23149/is-it-possible-to-create-evaluatable-cell-which-will-be-automatically-overwritte) seems relevant.  Doesn't look possible to sort out easily.

Comment: @Szabolcs I ran into another issue when using your solution.  Could you have a look at my edit?  Thanks!